# EF How it implements 'On Delete Rules'

Tags: entity-framework

Just learning EF, coming from a different ORM tool. I am looking for these delete options. I can't find them so do they exist?  Or how are they done in EF?

On Delete: I am familiar with 4 options on a relationship when an object is deleted.  I only see one in EF as of now:

1. Cascasde (EF has this I see, great)
2. Deny/Throw (ORM I have used handles this by throwing an exception if you try to delete an object hat has related records for the given relatuionship )

   **Example:**  *Customer -> Orders*  (If I try to delete a Customer with related Orders the Delete is denied)
3. Set Null (ORM I have used handles this by automatically setting the FK to null in the related table)
4. None (EF has this I see, great) - No Action

   **Example:** *DepartmentSupervisor(Employee) <- Department* (If you delete the Employee the DepartmentSupervisor FK in the Department table is set to null)

Answer (score 0):

EF does not support check constraints, you need to define check constrains at the table level using SSMS. Right click on the table, choose 'Design' then right-click again and choose 'Check Constraints' you'll be able to define any 'On Delete Rules' there...

Comment: Allready did that, thanks, I was hoping EF would do what i am familiar with and catch it before it goes round trip to the database.